# How to use the variable declared in one module to be used in other module function access vba

Tags: vba, ms-access

Is there any way that we can use variable declared in one module and use that variable in a function defined in other module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Declare a variable at module level like this:

```
Public myvar As String
```

It can then be accessed from other modules.

Note, however, that global variables like this are almost never a good idea.